# Где правильно открывать транзакцию с точки зрения архитектуры

Tags: java, база-данных, архитектура, транзакции

Язык специально не указываю, думаю вопрос актуален для бекэнда на любом языке.

Предположим у нас есть некая банковская операция (очень упрощенно):

```
class AccountManager {

  private BalanceRepository repository;

  void sendMoney(int userIdFrom, int userIdTo, double money) {
    double balanceOfuserFrom = repository.find(usedIdFrom);
    double balanceOfuserTo = repository.find(usedIdTo);
    repository.save(usedIdFrom, balanceOfUserFrom - money);
    repository.save(usedIdFrom, balanceOfUserTo + money);
  }
}
```

И тут чтобы все было консистентно, нам нужна транзакция:

```
void sendMoney(int userIdFrom, int userIdTo, double money) {
  SomeORM.openTransaction();
  ...
}
```

Или как это я часто вижу в Java, Spring:

```
@Transactional
void sendMoney(int userIdFrom, int userIdTo, double money)
```

Вот только как я понимаю, с точки зрения архитектуры это не правильно, потому что мы используем логику, принадлежащую к инфраструктуре (БД, ОРМ), внутри сервисов. И вообще сама суть абстракции репозитория ломается, ведь если мы заменим реализацию на чистый JDBC или вовсе какую нибудь монгу, транзакция совершена не будет.

Первое что лично мне приходит в голову, это вынесение самой логики транзакции в репозиторий:

```
interface BalanceRepository {
  void exchange(int userFrom, int userTo, double amount);
}
```

Собственно вопрос, кто нибудь вообще об этом задумывался, может где-то уже описан архитектурный подход к данному вопросу?

Answer (score 0):

Поведение - sendMoney() вынести в интерфейс и @Transactional выставить интерфейсу, тогда реализация всегда будет под транзацией и никто не забудет поставить @Transactional над методом или классом в целом.